# Unable to access private variables inside of static functions

Tags: c++, class, oop, static, friend

I'm trying to make a small mini game where a `class Hero` interacts with `class Enemy`variables using `friend` but the code is unable to compile and gives me the forward declaration error

```
#include <iostream>

class Enemy;

class Hero
{
    friend class Enemy;
private:
    static int hp, power;
public:
    Hero *h1;
    Hero ()
    {
        hp = 50;
        power = 10; 
    }
    static void attackEnemy (Enemy *e1, Hero *h1);
};

static void Hero::attackEnemy(Enemy *e1, Hero *h1)
{
    e1->hp -= h1->power;
}

class Enemy
{
    friend class Hero;
private:
    static int hp, power;
public:
    Enemy ()
    {
        hp = 15;
        power = 10;
    }
    void attackHero ();
};

int main ()
{
    Enemy *e1 = new Enemy ();
    Hero *h1 = new Hero ();

    h1->attackEnemy(Enemy *e1, Hero *h1);

    return 0;
}
```

I was told that `static` functions and variables are able to prevent this error as they are `global` as it pre-compiles the build

Answer (score 3):

There are two main issues here.

First, when defining `Hero::attackEnemy`, the `static` qualifier is invalid here.  The member is already declared as `static` in the class definition, so no need to apply it here as well.

Second, at the time `Hero::attachEnemy` is defined, the `Enemy` class still has not been defined.  You need to move the definition of `Hero::attachEnemy` *after* the definition of `class Enemy`.

```
class Enemy;

class Hero {
    ...
};

class Enemy {
    ...
};

void Hero::attackEnemy(Enemy *e1, Hero *h1)
{
    e1->hp -= h1->power;
}
```

Also, this is not a valid function / method call:

```
h1->attackEnemy(Enemy *e1, Hero *h1);
```

You want:

```
h1->attackEnemy(e1, h1);
```

Comment: just one minor but important correction, ...the member is already declared as static (not defined as you wrote)

Comment: @dsp_user Thanks.  Edited.